# Why does TreeSet's add method behaves differently in different JREs?

Tags: java, set, classcastexception, treeset

I try to add objects of Employee class to a TreeSet. I don't implement Comparable or Comparator interface. But the add method code behaves differently in different systems. Why so? Code snippet below:-

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TreeSetTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Employee> set = new TreeSet<Employee>();
    set.add(new Employee());
//  set.add(new Employee());
//  set.add(new Employee());
 }
}
```

On the current system (Win 10), whether I write set.add() method once or thrice. It always throws ClassCastException at runtime.
But talking of this question- [Why does TreeSet throws ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943031/why-does-treeset-throws-classcastexception)
The user there has written, that he doesn't get exception when he uses add method only once.

Also, in another system (Win 7), yesterday I had tried adding object 3 times, calling set method thrice, and there is no ClassCastException!! The size of set remains 1 only, so it appeared that multiple objects are just NOT getting added to set.

So what could be the reason for different-different kind of behavior of add method?

Comment: If anything, it would be the JRE version, not the Windows version.

Comment: @shmosel yes, so I guess different window version will have different JREs as well.

Comment: They may or they may not. Why don't you check?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I just copy-pasted it from my system. Win 10 running Java 8, but project running on 1.6 version.

Comment: If you already know the cause of the error, namely not implementing `Comparable` _or_ providing a custom comparator during construction, then why ask the question?  Note that a comparison for ordering doesn't actually need to be done until adding the _second_ item.  Maybe there is a slight change in implementation between Java 6 and Java 8.  In any case, you should not be using a sorted set without some notion of a comparator present.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because I am interested to know the internal behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TreeSet.add()` delegates to `TreeMap.put()`, which has differing behavior in Java 6 and Java 8.

[Java 6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29):

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    Entry<K,V> t = root;
    if (t == null) {
        // TBD:
        // 5045147: (coll) Adding null to an empty TreeSet should
        // throw NullPointerException
        //
        // compare(key, key); // type check
        root = new Entry<K,V>(key, value, null);
        size = 1;
        modCount++;
        return null;
    }
    ...
```

[Java 8](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29):

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    Entry<K,V> t = root;
    if (t == null) {
        compare(key, key); // type (and possibly null) check

        root = new Entry<>(key, value, null);
        size = 1;
        modCount++;
        return null;
    }
    ...
```

As you can see, the earlier version had the `compare()` line commented out for some reason, but it was added back in the later version. Hence the exception you're seeing for the first element.

See here also: [Why TreeSet can be used as a key for TreeMap in jdk 1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634083/why-treeset-can-be-used-as-a-key-for-treemap-in-jdk-1-6)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that. Let me read the implementation detail of the classes, to have more clarity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I had a quick look at the implementation of TreeMap class and you are perfectly right about this. In Java 6, the compare method is commented, but it is uncommented in Java 7 and 8. So it will throw ClassCastException in Java 7 and 8, but not in 6.